# CoreData - Memory - Multiple NSManagedObjectContexts - Terminating due to Memory Pressure

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, core-data

**Problem:** After running for about 30 - 60 minutes my application terminates due to memory pressure.

*THINGS TO NOTE:  This application is a proof of concept application that will never be in the App-Store.  It is distributed via HockeyApp and thus can (if necessary) use funky API calls*

I'm looking for some advice about the following things:

1. Do I need to change my data Model
2. Do I have a fatal flaw in my data logic

My core data setup is a follows:

*Entity:* `FlightRecording` [one-to-many relationship with `AHRSMessage`]

*Entity:* `AHRSMessage` [many-to-one relationship with `FlightRecording`]

I am using an off board wifi device that spits out messages (about 13-20 a second) which are captured by a background thread in my application.

**Core Data Setup**

- Single parent NSManagedObjectContext: `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType`
- Multiple child NSManagedObjectContext: `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType`

I'm using a single parent NSManagedObjectContext for my "foreground thread".  This context is initialized in the ApplicationDelegate with a `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType`

```
_managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
[_managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
```

And passed into the background class in an initialization call.  A child context is then spawned off this main context to handle the bulk of the data writing.

Child Contexts are used to handle the majority of the data collection. At certain times the child contexts get written to parent, and a new one is created using the following functions:

```
if (msgCount % 50 == 0) {
              // Child Save!

    NSLog(@"Saving SDatas");
    __block NSManagedObjectContext *currentChild = [self getChildContext];
    [self incChildContext];


    // Parent-Child save methodology
    [currentChild performBlock:^{
        NSError *error;
        if (![currentChild save:&error]) {
            abort();
        }
        [parentObjectContext performBlock:^{
            NSError *error;
            if (![parentObjectContext save:&error]) {abort();}
        }];

        [currentChild reset];
    }];


    }
```

Because this code happens in a performBlock its possible to keep receiving messages and so in order to not have the application crash I immediately make a new childContext before I save off the "current" one.  In making a new context I check the array to see if the 1st context in the array can be removed.  In practice there are only 2 child contexts floating around at a time.

**As I said this app will never go in the AppStore I wrote a function to allow me to access the private variable _unprocessedInserts from NSManagedObjectContext**

```
//Add a new child context and potentially remove empty child context form array
- (void)incChildContext {
    if (
    ((NSManagedObjectContext *)[childContextArray firstObject]).getUnprocessedInserts == 0) {
        NSLog(@"Empty First");
        [childContextArray removeObjectAtIndex:0];
    }
    [childContextArray addObject:[self makeNewChildContext]];
}

//MAKE NEW CHILD CONTEXT
- (NSManagedObjectContext*)makeNewChildContext {
    NSManagedObjectContext *newChild =  [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];

    [newChild setParentContext:parentObjectContext];
    if (currentRecordingID != nil) {  // Pass the recordingObject across contexts
        [newChild objectWithID:currentRecordingID];

    }
    return newChild;
}

- (NSManagedObjectContext*)makeNewChildContext {
    NSManagedObjectContext *newChild =  [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
    [newChild setParentContext:parentObjectContext];
    if (currentRecordingID != nil) {
        [newChild objectWithID:currentRecordingID];

    }
    return newChild;
}
```

So everything is fine and dandy and it runs great except eventually we start running out of memory.  From using instruments it looks like the AHRSMessages are never going out of memory event hough I'm calling `[currentChild reset]` which I thought was supposed to invalidate all the messages or something like that.

Is there anything inherently wrong with this setup?

Is it possible that because of my one-to-many relationship between Flight and Message the messages are never invalidated and kept in memory until I'm done with the flight object?  Any suggestions on how to avoid running out of memory in this case?

Thanks!

Comment: Relationships are difficult, in that once they are fulfilled, they can hold many objects in memory until the relationship is invalidated (by refreshing the object using `refreshObject:mergeChanges:`). Also, are you sure these `AHRSMessages` objects are from the child contexts and not the main one?

Comment: Well I create them in the child context -> but I believe when I do save they get pushed over to the main context no?  [Is there a way to verify this by looking at the object? does it hold a pointer to the correct context?]

Comment: Each context has its own managed objects. They are not passed from context to context. Once you release a context, its objects are also released. Resetting a context does not release the objects, it just turns them into faults, but some minimal data is kept. You can find the context of an object by inspecting its `managedObjectContext` method.

Comment: If you are being terminated due to memory pressure, what does your application do in response to memory warnings? What does the allocations template in Instruments tell you about how your application is allocating memory?